# Where can I find ExpressionParseHelper?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

What is it and where to I get one?

Seriously. If you Google "ExpressionParseHelper" you will get tons of snippets using it but 0 references to where it comes from.

I even searched MSDN with bing and the only results are StackOverflow answers.

I'm using .net 4.

example: [Format Date On Binding (ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133671/format-date-on-binding-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a custom static method on the class named `ExpressionParseHelper`. Its not part of the framework. The code is on the answer you have linked to.