# Input with date format set from ViewModel and html class attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editorfor, date-formatting

I am working with razor view engine in asp.net mvc3.

Now, I need an input for a `DateTime` which should display the value in a fixed format (say `dd-MMM-yyyy`). So I can do:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

And in the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
```

But I need to add a class in the input. Which I think is not possible in `EditorFor`.
So I could use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "Date" })
```

But the display format does not work in this case.

`Model` can be null. So,

```
@Html.TextBox("StartDate", string.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", Model.StartDate))
```

will throw `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: why the first one is not working to add class??? `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "Date" })` Can your date return a null value I think the exception is because your date may be null

Comment: Thanks for the `ApplyFormatInEditMode`. I miss that parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ophelia's way is a quicker version of mine. But this way is useful if you're going to have a few date fields in your application. So this is the way i like to do it:

-> In your **solution explorer**, create a folder *inside* **Shared** called "**EditorTemplates**"

-> In there, add a new (**not** strongly typed) **Partial View**. Call it "`DateTime`".

-> Open this view, and remove any code in there, and throw the following code in there:

```
@model System.DateTime
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "date" /* + any other html attributes you want */ })
```

-> In your **ViewModel**, your date field should be like this:

```
[Display(Name = "My Date:"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
```

-> In your **main view**, and any view you want to use a date field, you can just use `EditorFor` on the property, like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDate)
```

You can initialize the date field in your controller or set a default date in your viewmodel's constructor.

Comment: Great answer, though you do not even need the DateTime EditorTemplate unless you are adding custom classes for DateTime EditorFor. You just need  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yy}")] in your ViewModel or Model and @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDateTime) will be formatted the way you defined it in the DisplayFormat attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I use this and its works fine:

```
    @Html.TextBox("ExpiryDate", String.Format("{0:ddd, dd MMM yyyy}", DateTime.Now), new { id = "expirydate" })
```

Hope this is what you mean/need :)

Comment: How would you format the date without using helpers?  Such as:  @Model.ExpiryDate